# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

getting error is NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. the error in my console is The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building quizpage(dirty, state: _quizpageState#213b6):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

The relevant error-causing widget was:
quizpage

```
class getjson extends StatefulWidget {    
  String langname;
  getjson(this.langname);

  @override
  State<getjson> createState() => _getjsonState();
}

class _getjsonState extends State<getjson> {
  late String assettoload;

  setasset() {
    if (widget.langname == "Science") {
      assettoload = "assets/python.json";
    } else if (widget.langname == "Maths") {
      assettoload = "assets/java.json";
    } else if (widget.langname == "History") {
      assettoload = "assets/js.json";
    } else if (widget.langname == "C++") {
      assettoload = "assets/cpp.json";
    } else {
      assettoload = "assets/linux.json";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setasset();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List? mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (mydata == null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Loading",
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return quizpage(mydata: mydata,);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List mydata;

  quizpage({required this.mydata});
  @override
  _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
}

class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
  final List mydata;
  _quizpageState(this.mydata);

  Color colortoshow = Colors.indigoAccent;
  Color right = Colors.green;
  Color wrong = Colors.red;
  int marks = 0;
  int i = 1;
  bool disableAnswer = false;
  int j = 1;
  int timer = 30;
  String showtimer = "30";
  var random_array;

      Map<String, Color> btncolor = {
        "a": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "b": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "c": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "d": Colors.indigoAccent,
      };

  bool canceltimer = false;
  genrandomarray(){
    var distinctIds = [];
    var rand = new Random();
      for (int i = 0;; ) {
      distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(10));
        random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
        if(random_array.length < 10){
          continue;
        }else{
          break;
        }
      }
      print(random_array);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    starttimer();
    genrandomarray();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  void starttimer() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        if (timer < 1) {
          t.cancel();
          nextquestion();
        } else if (canceltimer == true) {
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showtimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  void nextquestion() {
    canceltimer = false;
    timer = 30;
    setState(() {
      if (j < 10) {
        i = random_array[j];
        j++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
        ));
      }
      btncolor["a"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      btncolor["b"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      btncolor["c"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      btncolor["d"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      disableAnswer = false;
    });
    starttimer();
  }

  void checkanswer(String k) {
    
    if (mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
      marks = marks + 5;
      colortoshow = right;
    } else {
      colortoshow = wrong;
    }
    setState(() {
      btncolor[k] = colortoshow;
      canceltimer = true;
      disableAnswer = true;
    });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), nextquestion);
  }

  Widget choicebutton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10.0,
        horizontal: 20.0,
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () => checkanswer(k),
        child: Text(
          mydata[1][i.toString()][k] ?? "",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: "Alike",
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        color: btncolor[k],
        splashColor: Colors.indigo[700],
        highlightColor: Colors.indigo[700],
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 45.0,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        print("mydata = $mydata");
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{
        return await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    "Quizstar",
                  ),
                  content: Text("You Can't Go Back At This Stage."),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Ok',
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text(
                  mydata[0][i.toString()] ??"" ,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontFamily: "Quando",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  absorbing: disableAnswer,
                    child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        choicebutton('a'),
                        choicebutton('b'),
                        choicebutton('c'),
                        choicebutton('d'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    showtimer,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: can you show us mydata ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside quizpage class you have two `final List mydata`, you need to remove the one inside `_quizpageState` and replace all the usage of `mydata` with `widget.mydata` , like this:

```
if (widget.mydata[2][i.toString()] == widget.mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
      marks = marks + 5;
      colortoshow = right;
    } else {
      colortoshow = wrong;
    }
```

repeat this in all over your class.

Comment: i did but same error showing

Comment: did you repeat that for every mydata in your class? could you update your question with my answer?

Comment: yes but the error is showing in this part widget.mydata[1][i.toString()][k] ?? "",

Comment: this line is not in your code!

Comment: mydata[1][i.toString()][k] ?? "" this line

Comment: can you print("mydata = ${widget.mydata}) inside initstate and show me the result? @binoarin

Comment: this syntax is showing all the list of question with choices

Comment: I know, I want to see the data inside it.

Comment: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/chatty  ( 7839): uid=10128(com.example.samples) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 7839): mydata = quizpage.mydata
I/flutter ( 7839): mydata = quizpage.mydata